# NullPointerException in RadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener in APIS 15 & 16

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, radio-button, radio-group

Actually, I've to ask you a question about NPE in setOnCheckedChangeListener of RadioGroup. I've tested this code in APIs from 15 to 23, and only crashes is APIs 15 & 16.

**At first, i dont need to solve the NPE, i did it. I need to know why android assigns a negative value to radioButton ID, which causes NULL return in 'group.findViewById'.**

Here we've the code:

```
private List<Question> listItems;

private Question getItem(int position) {
    return listItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.questionLayout, parent, false);
    return new VHQuestion(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final Question currentItem = getItem(position); 

    VHQuestion VHQuestion = (VHQuestion)holder;
    RadioGroup group = new RadioGroup(context);
    VHQuestion.listLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();

    if(currentItem.getOptions() != null){
        for(int i = 0; i< currentItem.getOptions().size(); i++) {
            CustomRadioButton radioButton = new CustomRadioButton(context);
            radioButton.setText("Question " + i);
            group.addView(radioButton, i);
            if (currentItem.getAnswer() != null ) {
                group.check(radioButton.getId());
                // More code...
            }
        }
    }

    group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            int radioButtonID = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            CustomRadioButton checkedButton = (CustomRadioButton) group.findViewById(radioButtonID);
            if (checkedButton.hasAnswer()) {
                // More code...
            }

        }

    });

    VHQuestion.listLayout.addView(group);

}

class VHQuestion extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    LinearLayout listLayout;

    public VHQuestion(View itemView) {
        this.listLayout = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_layout);
    }

}
```

Here we've the xml "questionLayout.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/side_margin_left"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/side_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/card_content_padding"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/card_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

With this code, i've this problems:

- `group.check(radioButton.getId())` does nothing.
- `checkedButton` mID attr has a **negative value** (e.g.: -1352790336).
- `CustomRadioButton checkedButton = (CustomRadioButton) group.findViewById(radioButtonID)` returns null.
- `findViewById`returns **null** if ID value is **negative**.
- `if (checkedButton.hasAnswer())` throws NPE.

So, i dont know why this NPE is thrown in this APIs.

I've solved the problem already doing it:

```
group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radiogroup, int checkedId) {

        if (shouldCallCheckedChange) {

            shouldCallCheckedChange = false;

            CustomRadioButton checkedButton = (CustomRadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 17) {
                for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
                        ((CustomRadioButton) group.getChildAt(i)).setChecked(false);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    if (group.getChildAt(i).getId() == checkedId) {
                        checkedButton = (CustomRadioButton) group.getChildAt(i);
                        checkedButton.setChecked(true);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (checkedButton.hasAnswer()) {
                // More code...
            }

            shouldCallCheckedChange = true;

        }

    }
});
...
```

And this code:
    `group.check(radioButton.getId());`

is replaced by:
    `radioButton.setChecked(true);`

So my question instead how to avoid the NPE is:
**Why android assigns negative value to RadioButton created dinamically?**

THANK YOU ALL!!

Comment: You never set an id to your `CustomRadioButton radioButton = new CustomRadioButton(context);`. Try doing that by `radioButton.setId(id)`.

Comment: @raxelsson I found that answer in other questions, but without explanation. Is there any Google Issue explaining why in APIs 15 & 16 is neccesary do a `radioButton.setId(id)`.

Comment: If you see View.java source code, you can see that default View id is `-1`. This ID is assigned to all views by default.

Comment: :point_up: - what @VladMatvienko said. 

SalvaCano, not sure if that's true. That you don't have to do it in APIs < 16. Does it work as expected on higher APIs?

Comment: @raxelsson, I know what I say, it's true: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r2.1/android/view/View.java#View.0mID

Comment: @VladMatvienko yes I know. Wasn't meant to you. Was meant to SalvaCano :) The line break I wanted was removed in the comment.. :)

Comment: @raxelsson, oh, sorry, misunderstood you

Comment: @raxelsson Yes, it works as expected on higher APIs. Just in 15 & 16 android assigns negative value.

Comment: In add, i've other class where i'm using a standar RadioButton, not custom, and there the app crashes in the same point. Android assigns a negative value there too.

Comment: from what I can see in the `View` class of API 23 a `View`  has the default id set to -1 as well. 
Sorry, from here on it would just be guessing game from my end. Don't know why it works as expected but only on API <16. If you find an answer, please post it here :)

Comment: @raxelsson what confusing. No, i mean, it crashes only in devices with APIs 15 & 16.

Comment: @vlad-matvienko the default ID assigned is -1 when you create the view, true. But when you add the view to the group, the assigned id changes to other negative value, like mentioned before (e.g.: -1352790336)

Answer (score 0):

I was testing my application... And I have seen

> setOnCheckedChangeListener

with overided function

> onCheckedChanged

was return negative id for radioButtons in api15 and api 16...
While tetsing, I recognize  RadioButtons had not id in xml...
This seems  weird bug... While it is working with  most common android apis  it does not work with api 15-16.. after I give id on xml, it is worked on 15-16.. Here is example

```
android:id="@+id/sunday"
```

just give id to each radiobuttons, you will see  it work